# undetected_chromedriver can't use Remote browser

Tags: python, selenium, browser, remote-access, undetected-chromedriver

[image]so I am currently using UC to bypass a bot protection on a website. For that, it works well but I recently used a new website that is called **browserless.io** . It is made to use selenium or other similarities, since this browserless.io is online browsers, I can't use UC since it doesn't include the function "Remote". I was wandering if someone had encountered the same problem and if someone had **a solution**. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you "use the website" meaning you tried automating something on that browserless.io ? Or did you use the tool browserless.io?

Comment: What do you mean  "it is made to use selenium or other similarities"? What kind of similarities? What do you mean made to use selenium? Are you implying that it uses selenium in the background? Or are you saying the website is used for anyone who wants to practice selenium?

Comment: Where, how and why are you wanting to use UC on what? This question is very vague.

Comment: @Mugen Hi, i am using Undetectable_chromedriver in python. In need to use the command webdriver.Remote() but with UC their isnt UC.Remove and i was wandering if there was a way to connect UC to the browserless.io API.

Comment: @Mugen i also added an image for you to understand the situation.

Comment: Okay. I got it now. When you say "can't do" - what is the error that you're getting? Does the code run? Does it fail? Does it just proceed forward and nothing happens? Please describe this in details.